# .NET composable streams: Relation between constructor mode and Read/Write methods

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I want to create composable streams.
Composable streams offer a Read and Write method with a buffer byte array  parameter. 
And their constructor contains a sourcestream and a Read/Write (or Direction or Mode or similar) parameter.
What is the relation between them? 
Do I have to implement all 4 read/write combinations?

Comment: Constructors never need 'to be implemented', excepting as exposed downstream. Readable streams must support Read. Writable streams must support Write. Where is the "4 read/write combinations" coming from?

Comment: The four combinations are Read() handling Read and Write Direction, and Write() handling Read and Write Direction.

Comment: You make no sense

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I am looking into a "How to write composable streams" that allow pumping data through chains of composable streams.